# How can I print current branch (of parallel branches) I am running at

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-blueocean

I got code that list all branches and stages for my pipeline

```
def build_jobs = [:]
build_jobs['1'] = {
    node('builder'){
        stage('A'){
            sh 'echo 1'
            printMyStage()
        }
        stage('B'){
           printMyStage()
           "error"
        }
    }
}
build_jobs['2'] = {
    node('builder'){
        printMyStage()
        sh 'echo 2'
    }
}
build_jobs['3'] = {
    node('builder'){
        stage('A'){
            printMyStage()
            sh 'echo 3'
        }
        stage('B'){
            printMyStage()
        }
    }
}
parallel build_jobs
```

at the beginning of the run I am getting the following prints:

```
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: 1)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: 2)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: 3)
```

How can I reach the variable that has the branch name so the printMyStage() function will print the branch it was running from?

For current code the output will be:

```
Branch: 1
Branch: 1
Branch: 2
Branch: 3
Branch: 3
```

I also tried to use PipelineNodeGraphVisitor( currentBuild.rawBuild ) but without success

Answer (score 0):

You can get the *head* `FlowNode` for the current thread via  undocumented [`CpsThread.current().head`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-cps/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsThread.html). Using [`FlowNode.getEnclosingBlocks()`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-api/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/graph/FlowNode.html#getEnclosingBlocks()) you can get the parent blocks and with some conditions you can determine the branch nodes.

Complete scripted pipeline example with nested `parallel` branches:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.graph.FlowNode
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.LabelAction
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ThreadNameAction

node {
    def build_jobs = [:]
    
    build_jobs['1'] = {
        stage('A'){
            printMyStage('#1.A')
        }
        stage('B'){
           printMyStage('#1.B')
        }
    }
    build_jobs['2'] = {
        
        def nestedParallel = [:]
        
        nestedParallel['3'] = {
            stage('A') {
                printMyStage('#3.A')
            }            
        }
        nestedParallel['4'] = {
            stage('A'){
                printMyStage('#4.A')
            }
            stage('B'){
                printMyStage('#4.B')
            }
        }
        
        parallel nestedParallel
    }
    
    parallel build_jobs
}

// Get list of enclosing branches from "parallel" statement for given FlowNode
@NonCPS
List<FlowNode> getEnclosingBranches(FlowNode node) {
    List<FlowNode> enclosingBlocks = new ArrayList<>()
    for (FlowNode enclosing : node.getEnclosingBlocks()) {
        if (enclosing != null && enclosing.getAction(LabelAction.class) != null) {
            if (enclosing.getAction(ThreadNameAction.class) != null) {
                enclosingBlocks.add(enclosing)
            }
        }
    }

    return enclosingBlocks
}

// Print current branch name(s)
void printMyStage( String prefix ) {
    def branches = getEnclosingBranches( CpsThread.current().head.get() )
    if( branches ) {
        echo "$prefix ${branches.displayName}"
    }
}
```

**Output** (the order is random because of parallelism):

```text
#1.A [Branch: 1]
#3.A [Branch: 3, Branch: 2]
#4.A [Branch: 4, Branch: 2]
#1.B [Branch: 1]
#4.B [Branch: 4, Branch: 2]
```

The function `printMyStage()` lists the names of all parent branches. If you only need immediate parent, use `branches[0].displayName`.

Comment: I need way without passing the name

Comment: @ZivM I've just found a way using `CpsThread.current().head` as a starting point.